# How do I join a many-to-many table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have model A and model B with relation of many-to-many, thus I have a 3rd table (say C) that hold information per each. I'm using MySql.

So my model something like this:

```
class a < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :c
end

class b < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :c
end

class c < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :a
    belongs_to :b
end
```

And of course c holds columns of a_id & b_id.
This is the existing model.

Now I need a new model class, that among others holds a_id & b_id (for complex reasons it need a & b and not c, since it needs all the existing & future C entries for a & b, for example).

```
class d < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    belongs_to :a
    belongs_to :b
end
```

My issue is about how to make a query that joins also c into it (this is to allow filtering and reduce the number of SQL queries when iterating over the results and accessing c).

**How do I perform such query?**
I think I know how to begin, but not how to end it..

```
D.where(<something>).includes(:a).includes(:b).joins(??????????)
```

Thanks

Comment: There are few problems with your question. First of all, I will suggest you to understand difference between include and joins(you can find that at stackoverflow). The way you have written query showed your confusion between include and join. Secondly how can you apply joins between C and D as per your question, they dont have any relations. To apply joins between them u need to have relations between them.

Comment: Thanks, but I do know the difference... I need the include since I need the eager loadinng andacess to fields of A & B.. I've tried to simplify the real model we have but maybe it confuses you, however we do have a relation. Anyway, I ended up with wriring a bit complex SQL join to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

### There are two approaches to doing this:

---

### has_many_through:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

With this approach you just have the two models and no intermediate model.
Note that the *database* **will** have a join table and will require a migration that creates it.
It will have two fields, each one a foreign key to the corresponding model/table.
That is the basic way.
As with many of the associations, the actual foreign keys are populated by Rails Actvie Record component which looks at the relationship between the models and figures out what is needed in terms of keys, extra records, etc.  This is convention over configuration, also know as the rails 'magic'.  Be careful to to duplicate the model/table keys or records (going "off the rails") and let rails manage that for you.

---

### has_and_belongs_to_many

Another way to achieve this is by using a has_many_through that includes a join model in the middle.
This is detailed here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association
With this approach you have an intermediate join table and you can add additional fields to it.  I have found that 'later' in a applications life it is common to want to add a boolean field or a timestamp to the join table (for example you can then easily select 'todays joins' and so having the has_many_through from the beginning, even if not strictly needed, makes adding field later very easy without re-writing the relationship.

---

Comment: You have it backwards. `has_and_belongs_to_many` does not have an intermediate model, whereas `has_many :through` does.